# Fitting a conditional logistic model with a Cox evaluator

Tags: python, survival

I can't find a way to reproduce the third part of the following link with the lifelines package in python:
https://stayconsistent.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/cox-model-and-conditional-logistic-model-back-and-forth/
I have tried with both the Coxph with strata and with a WeibullAFTFitter using interval censor but I couldn't get the expected outcome.

Any intuition on how to calibrate lifelines regression models to reproduce the conditional logistic model in python?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I coded up a replica, but I must ask *why* you are doing this? It's very complicated.

The differences are most likely a result of how the programs handles ties: lifelines only uses Efron-handling of ties, whereas this method requires Exact-handling of ties.

```py
df_ = pd.read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/CamDavidsonPilon/40c548eadc5c0eb6ad130fac87e2de46/raw/2543730b0e4556d1e59aeaad5d035e1774f8d3c5/test.csv")
df_ = df_.drop(['idcode', 'mygroup', 't0'], axis=1).reset_index(0)

cph = CoxTimeVaryingFitter().fit(df_, id_col='index', start_col='enter', stop_col='_t', event_col='union')

cph.print_summary()
```

Comment: You are correct. I have created another file this time with only 1 success per group and the result of CoxTimeVaryingFitter match the expected conditional logistic coefficients. Thanks

Comment: If I may ask an additional question, would it be valid to use a Log Logistic or Weibull AFT with that type of data?

Comment: Yes, but your new question has nothing to do with the conditional logistic model, right?

Comment: Thanks, I guess you are answering the question. It wouldn't then be a conditional Log Logistic model for example?

Comment: That’s right. They have different likelihoods.